# How to monitor intends produced inside activity in ActivityTestCase?

Tags: android, monitor, testcase

How to monitor intends produced inside activity in ActivityTestCase?
I need to get all intends produced by activity and assert on their data
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**An activity can have only one intent**

You can get that intent using `getIntent()` method

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
Intent intent=context.getIntent();
```